# using purrr to affect single columns of each dataframe in a list

Tags: r, tidyverse, purrr

still getting used to purrr and I have one of those questions that I think *should* be easy, but I don't know how to do it. All I want to do is convert the datetimes in the below, to dates with as.Date(). it's a list of dataframes. Been playing around but haven't found something that works yet... any help appreciated.

```
df <- data.frame(Date = seq.POSIXt(Sys.time(), Sys.time() + hours(24), by = "hour"),
             useless = "ignore me")
df2 <- data.frame(Date = seq.POSIXt(Sys.time(), Sys.time() + hours(1), by = "min"),
                    useless = "ignore me")
mylist <- list(df,df2)
mylist %<>% map(?????)
```

Comment: `mylist %>% map(~mutate_at(.x, vars(Date), as.Date))` or all in purrr, `mylist %>% map(dmap_at, 'Date', as.Date)`

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The canonical way to achieve your goal would be to combine `map` with some verb from `dplyr`, like `mutate_at`. Currently `purrr` still has the function `dmap_at`, but it will be removed from `purrr` in the future.

Hence, you would `map` over your list, and then modify the date column with `mutate_at`:

```r
library(purrr)
library(lubridate)
library(dplyr)

mylist %>%
  map(~mutate_at(.x, "Date", as.Date))
```

You could also use `at_depth`, which in the case of `at_depth(1, ...)` is equal to `map` and is therefore not necessary:

```r
mylist %>%
  at_depth(1, ~mutate_at(.x, "Date", as.Date))
```

The original approach, staying within `purrr`, was to use `dmap_at`:

```r
mylist %>%
  map(~dmap_at(.x, "Date", as.Date))
```

But since we now have `mutate_at` and `mutate_all` and friends, it is recommended to use them instead of `dmap`, `dmap_at` and so forth.

#### Data

```r
df <- data.frame(Date = seq.POSIXt(Sys.time(), Sys.time() + hours(24), by = "hour"),
                 useless = "ignore me")
df2 <- data.frame(Date = seq.POSIXt(Sys.time(), Sys.time() + hours(1), by = "min"),
                  useless = "ignore me")
mylist <- list(df,df2)
```

Answer (score 7):

You can combine `map()` with `mutate()` from the dplyr package (also tidyverse). `map()` can be used to apply `mutate()` each data frame in your list. `mutate()` can apply `as.Date()` to the `Date` column. You'd write it like this:

```
map(mylist, mutate, Date = as.Date(Date))
```

This line is saying:

- `map()`/apply the `mutate()` function to each object in `mylist`
- Each time `mutate()` is applied to an object, do it as if you were writing `mutate(object, Date = as.Date(Date))`

Full code:

```
library(lubridate)
library(purrr)
library(dplyr)

df <- data.frame(Date = seq.POSIXt(Sys.time(), Sys.time() + hours(24), by = "hour"),
                 useless = "ignore me")
df2 <- data.frame(Date = seq.POSIXt(Sys.time(), Sys.time() + hours(1), by = "min"),
                  useless = "ignore me")
mylist <- list(df,df2)
mylist <- map(mylist, mutate, Date = as.Date(Date))
```