# mutate_at to date across multiple tibbles

Tags: r, dplyr, lubridate, purrr

I have a list of tibbles, and a list of columns I wish to convert to date class.

```
library(tibble)
library(purrr)
library(lubridate)

df1 <- tribble(~date_a,    ~value_a,
               "2017-1-3", 10,
               "2018-2-7", 13,
               "2018-5-7", 35)

df2 <- tribble(~date_b,    ~value_b,
               "2014-1-7", 10,
               "2018-4-9",  6,
               "2018-5-8", 18)

list_dfs <- list(df1, df2)
list_dates <- c("date_a", "date_b")
```

Trying to use `purrr:map`, `dplyr:mutate_at` and `lubridate::ymd` to efficiently convert these, but getting the following error message:

```
list_dfs %>% map(~mutate_at(.x, vars(list_dates), ymd))
```

> ```
> Error: Strings must match column names. Unknown columns: date_b
> ```

[This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43218462/using-purrr-to-affect-single-columns-of-each-dataframe-in-a-list) seems similar, but I can't get mapping over tibbles and columns to work.

Do I need to do something clever with `purrr::map2`?

Comment: why "df1" and "df2" in quotes, also you should wrap it in `list()` not `c`?

Comment: Good point - my mistake! Will edit.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are correct, you can use `purrr::map2` where the first argument will be your list of tibbles and the second the list of column names

```
list_dfs <- list(df1, df2)
list_dates <- c("date_a", "date_b")

result <- map2(list_dfs, list_dates, ~ mutate_at(.x, .y, ymd))

result

# [[1]]
# # A tibble: 3 x 2
#   date_a     value_a
#   <date>       <dbl>
# 1 2017-01-03     10.
# 2 2018-02-07     13.
# 3 2018-05-07     35.

# [[2]]
# # A tibble: 3 x 2
#   date_b     value_b
#   <date>       <dbl>
# 1 2014-01-07     10.
# 2 2018-04-09      6.
# 3 2018-05-08     18.

for (i in seq_along(result)) {
    assign(paste0("df", i), result[[i]])
}
```

Comment: Thanks - this works. As a follow-up, how would I save these mutated columns within the original tibbles? `map2_df` and `map2_dfc` don't seem to do it

Comment: @PeterMacPherson I have updated my answer with a possible solution. It will work for your specific example but will not be generalisable if your dataframes are not called df1, df2, df3 etc.

Comment: If the `list_df` is named (ie: `list_dfs <- list('df1' = df1, 'df2' = df2)`) you can use `list2env(result, envir = .GlobalEnv)` to assign back the variables to the global environment

Comment: Brilliant thanks. Both these comments together solve the problem.

Comment: You should probably not do it though. I can't think of a case where it's reasonable to keep numbered data.frames out of a list if it's more than 2 or 3 of them.

Comment: and if you really must, you can use `tibble::lst(df1,df2)` instead of `list(df1,df2)` and you'll be able to use @GGamba's comment and avoid the loop on `assign`.